# Flat geometry(what would the drawing of this figure look like?including the values)

Tags: geometry

Consider a right-angled triangle and the circumference inscribed on it. The point of contact between the hypotenuse and the circumference determines in the hypotenuse segments 4meters and 6meters, what would this picture look like?
note: Show the question values in the figure.

Unfortunately, I only went here in development:
[image]

What would your development look like?

Comment: Hard to see what "determines in the hypotenuse segments A feet and B feet" means. It's unusual language, could you explain it?

Comment: I presume it means the length of the two segments on either side of the point of tangency.

Comment: @MatthewDaly That would be my guess also. (would be good if OP confirmed...)

Comment: Okay, I put in meters, improved?

Comment: There in the matter, I modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Given a point external to the circle, the two tangents to the circle are congruent.  So if $x$ is the length of the segment from the right angle to the circle by the tangent, you have 
$$(x+4)^2+(x+6)^2=10^2$$
from which I get $x=2$ just by inspection.  So this is a $6-8-10$ right triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\angle BIA=135^\circ$ (why?):

[image]

So, with the help of isosceles triangle $BEA$
with $\angle BEA=135^\circ$
and a circle through the points $A,B,E$ with the center $Q$,
we can find the incenter $I$ of $\triangle ABC$
and construct the points $F,G$ and $C$.

Comment: Can you tell me what the perimeter of this figure would be?

Comment: @funfun: This answer 
demonstrates the essential steps 
to construct the incircle and 
$\triangle ABC$ with straightedge and compass 
from given segments $AD$ and $BD$
in order to show how exactly
this picture look like, as asked.

It seems that the simplest way 
to find the numeric values of the side lengths 
of $AC$ and $BC$ 
is suggested in the answer by Matthew Daly.